# In mySql how to ignore past time when i compare any present or any datetime with any column having datetime?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sql query to ignore past time and show records when i compare with present datetime with datetime column.

My query:

```
select * from appoinments  WHERE (date(app.start_time) = date(NOW()))
```

start_time is a column having date and time both in format 'Y-m-d H:i:s'

i need to exclude past time from this query.
Because i'm getting extra records because of this

Comment: Obviously, use `>` operator.

Comment: Your query looks fine.

Comment: It would be great if you can included your current result and the desired result to  get a better view of what you are trying to accomplish here

Comment: Your query will include everything for today's date

Comment: @P.Salmon all i need is get resuls which are equal to present time or after present time not before the present time

Comment: Then you need >=